# Building a ReactJS app to run just in a browser

Tags: reactjs

Newbi question here: **Can you build a ReactJS app to run just in a browser, with no kind of web server?**

The app that I want to run has been created with `create-react-app` and I've tried building it with `npm run build`, but when I opened with a browser the index.html file from the build directory, the page was empty and in the console I got an ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error for a bunch of css and js files, even though the files can be found in the specified location.

I'm asking this because I want to build an app for my work, where I don't have admin rights and I just wanted to copy-paste it.

Comment: yeah just include the JS files in HTML and open it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the index.html file, where the files were imported, the path looked like this: `<script src="/static/js/1.944de9ae.chunk.js"></script>` where in fact you need to have a dot in from of the path, so like this: `<script src="./static/js/1.944de9ae.chunk.js"></script>`.

Sorry for the spam!